# How could I prevent vscode from opening new workspace when creating a new java project?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, dependencies

I recently start using vscode for java programs, but it's really hard to configure the settings, I set a empty workspace "goodskies" and use command palette to create no-build tools java projects, select the default folder but it always generates a new workspace and when I go back to my parent workspace, the main class warns to add a package declaration, I just want to write every program in one workspace not each for dependent workspace.

I am also confused about the package naming conventions,it seems that the package name should contains starting from the root directory of workspace to the parent root of the file, I don't why this works, why couldn't just specify the parent directory as package declaration?
how did the complier view delerations? Thanks!

So my question is that :

1. How to fix this properly?
2. How does package works and how to name it?

[image: Create a new java project]

[image: Just genereted a new workspace]

[image]

Comment: For the first question, I think you have not explained why you want to open the second one when you open a vscode. At this time, he will open a copy called "Explorer". Also note that if you open a java file in vs code without opening its folder, the Java language server may not work properly. For the second problem, vsocde retrieves files based on the workspace directory, not from the currently open file.

Answer (score 1):

The project without build tools does not allow containing sub-projects (which I guess in your case you want to have `pro1`, `pro2`... as subprojects).

But you can have multiple source roots, to do that, what you need to do is:

1. Creating a new project without build tools in a **new empty** folder.
2. Opening the newly created project, then you can create new folders `pro1/src`, `pro2/src`, at the root of the workspace folder. (in other words, beside the `src` folder).
3. Trigger the command `Java: Configure classpath`, then you can mark the `pro1/src`, `pro2/src` as the source root. Also the `src` at the root can be removed.